# Snakemake-create wildcards from output directory using checkpoints

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am parsing a multi-fasta file into single fasta file and I want to create wildcards for each file because the next rule needs to be parallelized for each file. My problem is that I am not able to create a wildcard from the resulting fasta file because the output changes dynamicaly depending on the multi-fasta file I have. Here is my code:

```
rule all:
    input:
        final = "kmers/{sample}/results.fasta",
        merge = "merge.fasta",
        arc = "All_fasta/"
       
checkpoint pyt:
    input:
        mm = "fasta.fasta"
    output:
        arc = directory("All_fasta/")
    script:
        "pyt.py"
        
def some_func(wildcards):
    checkpoint_in = checkpoints.pyt.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    # I don't know what to do here
    return "{sample}"


rule not_working:
    input:
        new_input = "{sample}"
    output:
        final = "kmers/{sample}/results.fasta"
    shell:
        "somecmd {input} > {output}"

rule merge:
    input:
        final = expand("kmers/{sample}/results.fasta",sample=sample)
    output:
        merge = "merge.fasta"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {ouput}"
```

In brief, I want to create a wildcard for each fasta entry I have in my multi-fasta input file.

thank you!

Comment: I think the second example in [data-dependent conditional execution](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) (the one with `checkpoint clustering`) is pretty much what you want to follow.

Comment: My problem with this example is that I don't want to cluster data. I want to create a list of data: a wildcard without expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

Input file `fasta.fasta` is:

```
cat fasta.fasta 
>a
AAAA
>b
CCCC
>c
TTTT
```

`sequence_names` produced inside `aggregate_input` is the list of sequence names from the original fasta file.

```
import glob

rule all:
    input:
        'merge.fasta',

checkpoint pyt:
    input:
        "fasta.fasta"
    output:
        all_fasta= directory("All_fasta")
    shell:
        # Split multifasta into single files. I assume this is what pyt.py
        # does. This is just a dummy script
        r"""
        mkdir {output}

        grep -A 1 '>a' {input} > {output}/a.fasta
        grep -A 1 '>b' {input} > {output}/b.fasta
        grep -A 1 '>c' {input} > {output}/c.fasta
        """

rule process_sequences:
    input:
        new_input= 'All_fasta/{sequence_name}.fasta',
    output:
        final= 'kmers/{sequence_name}/results.fasta',
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"

def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.pyt.get().output['all_fasta']
    fasta_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, '*.fasta')))
    sequence_names = [re.sub('\.fasta$', '', os.path.basename(x)) for x in fasta_files]
    return expand('kmers/{sequence_name}/results.fasta', sequence_name= sequence_names)

rule merge:
    input:
        final = aggregate_input,
    output:
        merge = "merge.fasta"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

I avoided the use of `glob_wildcards` since I find it too cryptic. I prefer to collect the output files using `glob.glob` and parse them using python built-ins.